# Counterexample to Line Integral depending on end points

Tags: complex-analysis

**Theorem**

The line integral $$\int_\gamma p\, dx + q\,dy$$ defined in $\Omega$, depends only on the end points of $\gamma$ if and only if there exists a function $ U(x,y) $ in $\Omega$ with the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial U}{\partial x} = p, \frac{\partial U}{\partial y} = q$.

I have shown an example of a conservative vector field, but what would be a counterexample to this?

Comment: Uh? A counterexample to **what** ?

Comment: where the line integral doesn't depend on end points

Comment: Can you state clearly what you want?

Comment: Just take a non-conservative field! And how would that be a counterexample to Green's Theorem??

Comment: This is not Green's Theorem.

Comment: It is called the fundamental theorem of line integrals or the Gradient theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem